# phpmyadmin import not inserting numbers correctly from csv

Tags: csv, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import some data from a CSV into my database with phpmyadmin. 
Here's a row from the CSV:

```
20101,1,grams,Good,AU,0.9999,Caesar,2017-06-14,12:33:44,RP
```

The first number I have set as a unique bigint(16). Somehow though, this gets imported as "101" instead of "20101", which causes a duplicate error because i already have a "101".

Why wouldn't the number fully read as "20101"?

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out. When saving the CSV from Excel, I was using the "CSV (UTF-8)" option. Don't know why that would make a difference, but when I switched to saving it as a plain CSV comma delineated, the file imported with no problems.